# Reposition UIButtons after zoom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview with an imageview on it. I am able to zoom the image view placed inside the scrollview. On top of it I have some uibuttons, which do not reposition after zoom.

How do I reposition UIButtons after zoom?

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `layoutSubviews` of the `UIScrollView` and do your positioning there?

Comment: No i didnt try.. is there any sample code to do it?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to implement the `scrollViewDidZoom:` delegate method of your scroll view delegate, determine the currently visible rectangle using `contentOffset` and `contentSize` properties of your `UIScrollView`, compute the new location of your buttons relative to the visible rectangle of the scroll view, and reposition your buttons into that rectangle by setting their `frame` property as desired.

Answer (score 1):

As Fisk mentioned, the UIScrollViewDelegate should help.  One of the delegate methods is:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
```

If you implement the UIScrollview delegate this method should get called when your scrollview is done zooming.  So in this method you can reposition your button after the zoom:

```
[yourButton1 setCenter:CGPointMake(newX,newY)];
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. However, whatever it is that you are doing, I believe [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) can help you.

This is a delegate for the scroll view that lets you know when it is scrolling. I never got where the buttons are supposed to be, but with this delegate I guess you can simply place them wherever they need to be.

Comment: I have already implemented UIScrollview delegate and able to zoom image successfully, but I do have UIButtons on image view, which I need to reposition on zooming